# Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found [Gentoo]

Tags: memcached, gentoo

TERMINAL

```
> php -m
...
memcache
...


> php -i | grep -i memcache
/etc/php/cli-php5.3/ext-active/memcache.ini
memcache
memcache support => enabled
memcache.allow_failover => 1 => 1
memcache.chunk_size => 32768 => 32768
memcache.default_port => 11211 => 11211
memcache.default_timeout_ms => 1000 => 1000
memcache.hash_function => crc32 => crc32
memcache.hash_strategy => standard => standard
memcache.max_failover_attempts => 20 => 20
Registered save handlers => files user mm memcache 


> php -m | grep -i memcache
memcache
```

PHP.INI

```
/etc/php/apache2-php5.3/php.ini
/etc/php/cgi-php5.3/php.ini
/etc/php/cli-php5.3/php.ini
in all I wrote: extension=memcache.so
```

THEN

```
>/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Stopping apache2 ...
...
 * Starting apache2 ...
```

PS: command "emerge dev-php5/pecl-memcached":

```
emerge: there are no ebuilds to satisfy "dev-php5/pecl-memcached".
```

So I dont know what to do. Please help.
By the way the same problem I have with browscap. I do "browscap = '/usr/local/lib/browscap.ini'" in all php.ini, restart server. And in phpinfo() the Browscap has "no value".

Comment: I have the same problem on Debian. Nothing about memcache in PHPINFO.

Comment: Okay, on Debian I make some profit. Now I see memcache and memcache in phpinfo. But it is still Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found.

Comment: But memcache NO in echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211

Comment: I solve the problem on Debian. I forgot use "sudo apt-get install php5-memcache".

Answer (score 1):

There is no **php5-dev** category in portage. Concurrent installation of different versions of dev-lang/php (and other ebuilds) are handled with portage SLOTS. The package you are looking for is: `dev-php/pecl-memcached`.

Answer (score 0):

The package you need is `dev-php/pecl-memcache` and it'll add the relevant memcached.ini

Maybe packages have changed, simply run: `eix memcache`
to see what's on offer.